# PhantomJS not finding elements on html page that Chrome and Firefox can

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I am running automated tests using selenium and c# and using PhantomJS as a headless browser to run the tests.  Some of the tests have recently started failing inconsistently after some new google analytics code was added to the site.  The tests are sometimes failing to find form elements on the page but when run in a normal browser like chrome they pass every time.  The tests are usually failing on a wait until visible statement.  The google analytics code can't be removed.

I debugged by getting a copy of the html code being ran when the tests fail and the code has had all elements after the head stripped out and some script tags are missing in the head as well.  There was even a closing html tag after the head.  Just wondering if anyone had seen similar issues before and knew how it might be fixed without having to remove the analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use PhantomJs. As PhantomJs is not so much maintain these days. You can use chromedriver in headless mode.

you just need to add options as headless as below :-

```
   chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

The full code in Java will appear as below:-

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
 driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Had considered that as a solution but I couldn't get a definitive answer on whether headless chrome supports screenshots yet.  Very handy feature for debugging failed tests.

Comment: Yes you can use screenshot in headless mode.

Comment: As I earlier said there is some maintainance issue with phantomJS.. while try to put some wait and then try the result. while your question is unclear on which attribute/DOM value you are facing issue. add the HTML and code you have tried .. This is how stackoverflow works

Comment: I understand but there are confidentiality issues with my company so have to be careful about what code I post